# In Keras/TF, is there a way to pre-train a model and reuse it to test other possible layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

[image: Example of what I am trying to do]

The picture above is only an example. What I am trying to achieve is to train the DenseNet201 and then connect it to a few other layers before having a FC or output layer. I want to test a few models but training the DenseNet + model takes a very long time for each model.

Is there any way to do this? And even if the predictions are not totally correct, would this shine some light on which model would be the best to follow the DenseNet?

Comment: There are a lot of way to do this. Please share what you've tried so far and make your question more specific

Comment: If you want to keep the DenseNet trainable, each different model following the DenseNet will have a different feedback on the DenseNet. It seems not reasonable to keep the same weights in the DenseNet for all tested models. Backprop will train the DenseNet differently for each model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy to do with the Keras [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

densenet = DenseNet(....., include_top=False)

inp = Input(shape=(some_input_shape))
ds_features = densenet(inp)
out = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(ds_features)

model = Model(inp, out)
```

In this code you instantiate a DenseNet somehow, and then pass a keras tensor through it (the `densenet(inp)` part), and you get an output tensor that you can feed to other layers. Then you build a model specifying the input and outputs. You can do this multiple times with different layers, building different models, and the same DenseNet weights will be used.

Comment: Yes, as Matias mentioned, this is very easy to do with Keras. Just to add a reference, check out this page from their documentation: https://keras.io/applications/#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes The example is using Inception as an example, but you can load your custom model as well.